# Infinite loop while reading from a file part2

Tags: c, file, loops, position, infinite

I was trying to read from a file of `int` each line separately and to terminate my loop when finding a '\n' but the problem with the lines was that in the end of each line first was a space char and then a newline one so I couldn't use the `scanf()` and then `fgetc` to terminate my loop. I thought to keep my position in the file and do two `fgetc` so when I encounter the space and then the new line to keep the last and terminate the loop otherwise return to my previous position and keep reading. My problem is that I somehow created an infinite loop and don't know how to fix it. Can someone please help?

```
do
{ 
  fscanf(fp, "%d", &temp);
  a = fgetc(fp);
  curPos = ftell(fp);
  if (a == '\n') break;
  a = fgetc(fp);
  fseek(fp, curPos, SEEK_SET);
} while(a != '\n');
```

File format:

```
0 1 2'SPACE''NL'
4 20 555'SPACE''NL'
etc
```

Comment: If you're only doing a single-character look-ahead, why not use `ungetc`?

Comment: I am not following, I do not want to replace something isn't that the usage of `ungetc`?

Comment: It's one of the usages - you can also use it to undo the last `fgetc` - just use the character you read (in this case, `ungetc(a, fp)`).

Comment: IT WORKED!!!!! Thanks I am 3 days now trying to find a working solution!!!!